# Switching two view controller, back function not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

im have two view controller `UserListView` and `UserProfileView`! 
in `UserListView` view controller i'm  have a button for swtich to `UserProfileView` and here is code.

UserListView.m - Click Action

```
- (IBAction)SettingClick:(id)sender
{
    UserList *UserProfile = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserProfileView"];
    [self presentViewController:UserProfile animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And code working fine, when user switch to profile (UserProfileView) have a close button back to `UserListView` and here is code.

UserProfileView.m - Close click action

```
- (IBAction)CloseClick:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UserProfile *UseList = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserListView"];
    [self presentViewController:UseList animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

in this code i will using `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` to close `UserProfileView` view controller for low ram usage and it work.

But affter i close `UserProfileView` i want to open this view controller again and it do not work, `UserProfileView` not showing again??

i using xcode 5 and building an App for ios 7, please help.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't think you need to re-initstantiate UserProfile upon close. Try this: `- (IBAction)CloseClick:(id)sender { [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; }`. Does that suite your needs?

Comment: You want to close UserProfile and re open the SAME view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, when you call `SettingClick:` your app is displaying a `UserList`. So, when you dismiss a view controller presented on top of it, you should go back to `UserList` without the need for presenting it again. So you can try with:

```
- (IBAction)CloseClick:(id)sender
{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
```

This will work unless you had originally presented `UserList` as well. In this case, `UserList` will be dismissed with the top controller. In this case, you can delay presenting a second time `UserList` after dismissing `UserProfile`, and it should work.

In the latter case, I would suggest you to use a navigation controller instead of simply presenting your controllers like you are doing. As you see, it is not really straightforward and you will get into catches of any kind. Presenting a controller works ok when you present just one controller at a time. On the other hand, if you instantiate a `UINavigationController`, this will handle the controllers' hierarchy for you.

Answer (score 0):

use this -

```
- (IBAction)CloseClick:(id)sender
{
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

This will return to your previous view when u click that button that has been linked with this action